# How to read Azure Ad User CompanyName Attribute using credentials in java

Tags: java, azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-app-registration

I am trying to get Azure AD user Attribute CompanyName using user id, passwor, client id, and Tenant Id using java.

Reffered this Doc: <https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=java> under username/password provider.

My Azure AD setup:

1. in azure ad, ive created a user with company name property.
2. Created Azure App registration, with localhost redirect URI & marked on id tokens under authetication section,

- created Client secret,
- Added role for App registration, added user to app regisitrion with that role under enterprise application.
- i've used client id, tenent id, user id, password correctly also tested these credentials with spring boot project there it is working fine (able to access comapnyName) after Login (SSO), but my requirement is i need to fetch user comapy details without SSO, for api use case.

here is my java code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import com.azure.identity.UsernamePasswordCredential;
import com.azure.identity.UsernamePasswordCredentialBuilder;
import com.microsoft.graph.authentication.TokenCredentialAuthProvider;
import com.microsoft.graph.models.User;
import com.microsoft.graph.requests.GraphServiceClient;


public class azureADUserAuth {
    final String clientId = "YOUR_CLIENT_ID";
    final String tenantId = "YOUR_TENANT_ID"; // or "common" for multi-tenant apps
    final String userName = "YOUR_USER_NAME";
    final String password = "YOUR_PASSWORD";
    final List<String> scopes = Arrays.asList("User.Read"); 

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        try {
UsernamePasswordCredential credential = new UsernamePasswordCredentialBuilder()
    .clientId(clientId).tenantId(tenantId).username(userName).password(password)
    .build();

    if (null == scopes || null == credential) {
            throw new Exception("Unexpected error");
        }
    TokenCredentialAuthProvider authProvider = new TokenCredentialAuthProvider(scopes,credential);
GraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient .builder() .authenticationProvider(authProvider) .buildClient();
    
    User me = graphClient.me().buildRequest().get();
    System.out.println(me.companyName);
   }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

here code printing 5 errors in console

1. com.microsoft.graph.core.ClientException: Error executing the request
2. Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.azure.core.exception.ClientAuthenticationException: Failed to acquire token with username and password
3. Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.azure.core.exception.ClientAuthenticationException: Failed to acquire token with username and password
4. Caused by: com.azure.core.exception.ClientAuthenticationException: Failed to acquire token with username and password
5. Caused by: com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.MsalServiceException: AADSTS7000218: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_assertion' or 'client_secret'.
   Trace ID: 8e0854e2-6d51-422e-b2d5-47b6303b2400
   Correlation ID: 5df6d392-3bcb-4730-9666-4ae8f9131681
   Timestamp: 2023-08-18 18:00:51Z

Please Help!

Comment: You need to either include `client_Secret` parameter in your code or enable **public client flows** option like [this](https://i.imgur.com/mdfUYbO.png).

Comment: Hi sridevi, thanks it's working now. But I need to get companyname attribute for this I have added user.companyname under oidc based sign on but still iam getting null value with S.O.P(me.companyName); why? Any idea ?

Comment: You need to use `$select` query to fetch companyName like this: `User user = graphClient.me().buildRequest().select("companyName").get();`

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to generate access token using **username password** flow via Postman without passing `client_secret`, I got **same error** as below:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token
client_id:appId
grant_type:password
scope:User.Read
username:sri@xxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com
password:xxxxxxxxxx
```

**Response:**

[image]

> To **resolve** the error, you need to either include `client_secret`
> parameter in your code or enable **public client flow** option.

In my case, I enabled **public client flow** option in my Azure AD application like this:

[image]

After enabling public client flows option, I am able to get access token without including `client_secret` parameter:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token
client_id:appId
grant_type:password
scope:User.Read
username:sri@xxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com
password:xxxxxxxxxx
```

**Response:**

[image]

You can decode the above token in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms) website to check permissions in **`scp`** claim:

[image]

When I used this token to call **`/me`** endpoint, I too did n't get **companyName** property in response like below:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me
```

**Response:**

[image]

> Note that, only limited properties are returned by **`/me`** endpoint
> by default. To get specific properties like **[companyName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties:%7E:text=on%20null%20values%29.-,companyName,-String)** in
> response, you need to use **`$select`** query parameter in graph call.

When I ran below query with $select parameter, I got  **companyName** in response successfully:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$select=companyName
```

**Response:**

[image]

To confirm that, I checked the same in Portal where user's **company Name** attribute value is same as below:

[image]

**Sample java code:**

```java
GraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider( authProvider ).buildClient();

User me = graphClient.me()
    .buildRequest()
    .select("companyName")
    .get();

System.out.println(me.companyName);
```